# How to get a SQL Server stored procedure returned rowset using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

My question is in close connection to [stackoverflow/9915788](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915788/how-to-get-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-return-value-using-pyodbc).

I am using pyodbc to upload data to an external SQL database and for this I use a stored procedure of that database. This procedure returns two things:

- a rowset (a single row which contains the text "Success" if the procedure worked fine or the text "Fail" followed by any available reason if it failed)
- an integer value (0 for success, -1 for failure)

I managed to read out the integer value using the approach described in the link above, but I would like to read out the rowset as well   because I would like to get further information in case of any errors.

Any ideas how to do this? I'm not a SQL expert, but in my understanding a rowset should be a "cursor like" object since it should be possible to loop that row; but how do I get this in a select statement?

This is how I get the integer value:

```
def CallStoredProc(conn, procName, *args):
    sql = """SET NOCOUNT ON;
            DECLARE @ret int
            EXEC @ret = %s %s
            SELECT @ret""" % (procName, ','.join(['?'] * len(args)))
    return conn.execute(sql, args).fetchall()
```

But I have no idea how to get the row, which should also be available somewhere..

Comment: can you show us what youve tried

Comment: I added a code example of the integer value readout. For the row readout I have no concrete idea and desperately hope you could give me any hint...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the following stored procedure in SQL Server

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsItGord] 
    @p1 varchar(50) = 'everybody'
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF @p1 = 'Gord'
    BEGIN
        SET @retval = 0;
        SELECT 'Success' AS response;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @retval = -1;
        SELECT 'Fail - ' + @p1 + ' is not Gord.' AS response;
    END
    RETURN @retval;
END
```

the following pyodbc code

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
sql = """\
DECLARE @return_value int;
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[IsItGord] ?;
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value;
"""
crsr = cnxn.execute(sql, ("Gord"))
data = crsr.fetchall()
print(data)
crsr.nextset()
data = crsr.fetchall()
print(data)
```

prints

```
[('Success', )]
[(0, )]
```

and if I change the `.execute()` to

```python
crsr = cnxn.execute(sql, ("Fred"))
```

it prints

```
[('Fail - Fred is not Gord.', )]
[(-1, )]
```

Comment: Thanks Gord for your nice answer! 
I tried this out but the problem seems to be that the cursor.nextset() gives a boolean False and therefore I cannot call the next Response (if I try a fetchall() after calling nextset() I get "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.")
I will contact the database admin and ask how the procedure returns the row; it seems to work different than your example, otherwise I would expect it to work this way.

Comment: When executing SQL Server stored procedures (or possibly any SQL script) from Python, I found that you had to remove any USE { database name } instructions otherwise the "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query" error occurred. This is likely because pyodbc has already made a connection to a particular database and any attempt to change databases without authentication through a valid connection process should fail.

Comment: @mrduncle1 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59529459/2144390

Answer (score 1):

always use:  set nocount ON, before executing the stored procedure in SQL server.