# Connect to SQL server using pyodbc and sqlalchemy, cannot use "use database_name;"

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

My code is as follows：

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session


def list_dbs():
    sql = """
            use master;
            SELECT name
            FROM   sys.databases;
        """
    try:
        odbc_connect = "DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=master;port=1433"
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % urllib.quote_plus(odbc_connect),
                                          echo=True, connect_args={'autocommit': True})
        SessionFactory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = scoped_session(SessionFactory)
        result = session.execute(sql)
        for v in result:
            print(v)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


list_dbs()
```

Then an error "This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically."

[image]

But then I remove "use master;" and it works:

[image]

[image]

Because I have many databases, I have to use "use databasename." Any ideas?

Comment: If you're defining the database to connect to (`master`) in `odbc_connect`, why do you need `USE master;` in your SQL anyway? The `USE` is redundant, as you've already connected to the correct database.

Comment: Are you able to run your SQL script directly on the server. I tried it and it worked correctly. Might this is a bug in the driver?

Comment: Also, any SQL Server only has one `master` database. Are you asking how to list the tables in each database rather than the databases on the server?

Comment: I have multiple databases on my instance, and I need to switch databases in the same SQL.And I've verified this SQL on the SSMS, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the issue discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/647).

As it stands now, you need to execute the `USE ...` separately and then execute your queries. Example:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    db_name = conn.execute(text("SELECT DB_NAME()")).fetchone()[0]
    print(f'Current database: {db_name}')  # Current database: myDb
    tables = conn.execute(text("SELECT TOP 3 name FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name")).fetchall()
    print(tables)  # [('MillionRows',), ('myTable',), ('person',)]
    conn.execute(text("USE master"))
    db_name = conn.execute(text("SELECT DB_NAME()")).fetchone()[0]
    print(f'Current database: {db_name}')  # Current database: master
    tables = conn.execute(text("SELECT TOP 3 name FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name")).fetchall()
    print(tables)  # [('MSreplication_options',), ('spt_fallback_db',), ('spt_fallback_dev',)]
```